# Она художник и её друзья спят

Tags: пунктуация

Если у нас есть предложение с двумя полными наборами однородных членов:

> "Она рисует" и "её друзья спят"

То запятая ставится:

> Она рисует, и её друзья спят

А что если один из наборов неполный, нет сказуемого, например:

> Она художник и её друзья спят

Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Comment: Не совсем ясна связь с наличием/отсутствием сказуемого. Если есть 2 независимых предложения, разделенных сочин. союзом "и", вроде бы, наличие запятой не должно вызывать сомнений?

Comment: Я про то, что становится ли предложение сложным, если не хватает сказуемого у одного из подлежащих? Если сложное - да, запятая нужна, но становится ли оно таковым...

Comment: "В огороде бузина, а в Киеве дядька" - запятая _ставится_.

Comment: Как раз со сказуемым тут все в порядке, глагол -связка "есть" в настоящем времени опускается плюс именная часть "художник".

Comment: @Alexander здесь понятно, потому что перед "а" запятая всегда ставится. А вот перед и далеко не всегда=)

Answer (score 5):

Надо различать **однородные сказуемые (запятая не ставится) и сложное предложение (запятая ставится)**, если есть **союз И**.

(1) ***Она рисует и слушает музыку.*** Это простое предложение с однородными сказуемыми. *Она* — подлежащее, *рисует и слушает* — два однородных сказуемых (к одному подлежащему).

(2) ***Она рисует, и ее друзья рисуют тоже.*** Это сложное предложение, оно состоит из двух простых предложений. *Она* — подлежащее,  *рисует* — сказуемое. *Друзья* — подлежащее, *рисуют* — сказуемое.

(3) ***Она художник, и её друзья спят*.** Это сложное предложение, оно состоит из двух простых предложений. *Она* — подлежащее,  *художник* — сказуемое. *Друзья* — подлежащее, *спят* — сказуемое.

В предложении (3) сказуемое **именное**, оно выражено не глаголом, а существительным. Глагольная связка ***быть*** в настоящем времени пропускается.

**Примечание**

В приведенных  примерах простые предложения **двусоставные** (подлежащее + сказуемое), но в сложное предложение могут входить **односоставные** простые предложения, например:

**Тишина**, и деревья в лесу словно застыли. **Очень тихо**, и деревья в лесу словно застыли.

В этих примерах первое простое предложение односоставное (только подлежащее или только сказуемое). Но запятая всё равно ставится.

Answer (score 2):

Разве количество частей сложного предложения определяется только количеством сказуемых? Подлежащие не менее значимо. Запятая нужна. В приведённом примере сказуемое выражено существительным (как в предложениях с тире), а ведь может быть и причастием, и наречием - не только глаголом. Кроме того, есть и односоставные предложения, где есть только подлежащее или только сказуемое. Например, назывным предложением зовётся предложение без сказуемого ('полная тишина'), и даже его использовать при создании сложных предложений можно

Примеры в интернете по запросу 'сказуемое выраженное '+часть_речи